# Show tasks Button for Publishing queue in Tridion making CMS Slow

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

When there are large number of items in the queue in tridion publishing queue the Clicking the show tasks Button again and again makes the DB slow. Because the DB query behind that is asynchronous. We cant stop someone from clicking the button again and again but is making CMS slow. Is there any patch or any solution???

Comment: SiteEdit 2009 and the new User Interface will notify the user (with a message in the message center) when their publish transaction (to the current publication target) has completed. Both do this by polling the publish queue, but (unlike your users apparently) they do check the queue at a consistent interval (every 30 seconds or 10 seconds by default). If you're willing to spend the effort, you could create something similar for the CME.

Answer (score 3):

Some of these Publishing Queue slowness could be avoided by purging your publishing queues on regular basis (schedule task) and also keeping database stats up to date and rebuilding indexes will help improve the performance better.

Purging Publication Queue documentation:
http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/idheading-259307200

Even if you implement the custom GUI extn or other solution which refreshes the queue at regular intervals, you could run into the same problems if you don't have maintenance tasks like purging queue/DB optimization.

Which version of Tridion you're running?. There is big difference on Publishing Queue between Tridion 2011 GA vs SP1 in terms of the filter for the user. Tridion GA user filter is not selected automatically, so when user check the tasks publishing queue returns the results for all users. This works correctly in SP1.

Comment: We are using Tridion 2011 GA. Is there any patch available for this user selection automatically??

Comment: This was fixed in SP1 and I don't think there is any hotfix available. Please check with Tridion Customer Support.